# How to create an Outlet or reference from a viewController in storyboard to our controller?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, xcode4.5

I created an application that started with UITabBarController

Something like this:

[image]

Now I want to refer that that UITabBarController in the code. How am I supposed to do so?

Should I right drag to application delegate? (Doesn't work).

I could use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentfier: but I do not want to create a new UITabBarController. I want to refer to the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where in code do you want to refer to it? If it's one of the controllers that the tab bar controller manages, then you can use self.tabBarController. If it's from the appDelegate you can use self.window.rootViewController.

Comment: Great. Correct answer. So that means no longer IBOutlet to view controllers isn't it?

Comment: I think it's generally true that you don't need outlets to view controllers, although, I'm sure there are circumstances that would require one.

Comment: There is no circumstances that would require one. I just do not like to use StoryBoardID or tags. I might make typing errors, etc.

Comment: Oh this one almost count, but then again, there is rdelmar.